# Custom fields added to Account object does not get pushed

Tags: salesforcedx

In my source org I have made modifications of the `Account` object by adding a number of fields. I then exported these fields via `sfdx force:source:pull` and files are now stored in `force-app/main/default/objects/Account/fields/Name_of_the_Field__c.field-meta.xml`

Unfortunately when I now try to create a new version of the package validation failing with error that custom fields can't be found. Apparently these are ignored by creating a new package version?

Do you know how can I make sure files are picked and included in package (version 2)?

Comment: Do you have the `force-app/main/default/objects/Account/Account.object-meta.xml` file as well? If not, you need it.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, @PhilW. I actually do have this file. That does not however influenced the outcome :(